# Insert Empty string From Excel To SQL(int)

Tags: sql, vba

I have a data in Excel that want to insert into SQL.

There are rows that have a blank, when I try to insert the data into SQL, the data is inserted as '0' instead of 'NULL'.

Example of data as below:

```
---------------------------------
Items          Total      Price
---------------------------------
Glue             4          $1
Socks            2          $7
Tumbler                     $40
Pen             10          $1
Eraser                      $0.5
---------------------------------

Items(char(50))
Total(int)
Price(float)
```

Does anyone know how can I insert the blank data as NULL instead of "0" ?

Below is what I have so far.

```
STRSQL = "INSERT INTO [Stationary].[dbo].[Stocks] ([Items],[Total],[Price])" & _
"VALUES ('" & Range("A" & i) & "','" & Range("B" & i) & "','" & Range("C" & i) & "')"
```

Really appreciate if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: allow null for total(int) column

Comment: Depending on risk and value of the database, you might also want to sanitise/escape the data you read from the cells to avoid malicious SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try replacing

```
& Range("B" & i) &
```

with

```
& IIf(Range("B" & i).value = "", "'Null'", Range("B" & i).value) &
```

Comment: This should work perfectly. One small enhancement, consider using `value2` in place of `value`, to protect against the (perhaps unlikely) scenario where someone messes with the formatting of that column on you. But, this enhancement is not mandatory.

Comment: @NAJAA BAZILAH: Glad I could help!